# Left and right equivalent of "upward" and "downward"?

Tags: single-word-requests, direction

Is there any single-word equivalent for "upward" or "downward" but for to the left and to the right? For example: "Please move that piece **to the left**".

Comment: Logic would lead us to "rightward" and "leftward." Common Internet sources would support that logic.

Comment: @RustyTuba Yes, I tried Google, they seem to be valid. However, I have never seen they are being used. Are they rare or old words?

Comment: Compared to "upward" and "downward," yes they're rare. It's more common (according to Google Ngram Viewer) to simply say (write) "to the right" and "to the left."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find **rightward** and **leftward** in mainstream dictionaries.

> rightward adj. or adv. \ˈrīt-wərd: [toward the right](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rightward)
>
> rightward - adv. & adj. - [To or on the right.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rightward)
>
> leftward -  adj. & adv. [To or on the left.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leftward)

Figuratively, **eastward (to the right) and westward (to the left)** might fit, if one assumes one is facing north (as Carl Smith has pointed out)

eastward (adj) in an easterly direction.
"they followed an eastward course"

adverb: eastward; toward the east.
"You could have moved your piece eastward."

Comment: Only if you're facing the North.

Comment: Cardinal directions don't really seem to fit here. They might if the asker was wondering about words that fit with "northward" and "southward." But say you're talking about design elements on a webpage; "eastward" and "westward" wouldn't be used.

Comment: @RustyTuba But I'm sure you would understand it, if I said "move it eastward".

Comment: I most certainly would, but I wouldn't advocate "eastward" as a generally useful equivalent of "rightward."

Answer (score 1):

The term *rightish* expresses a sense of  “to the right”.   From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rightish#English), *rightish* means “Somewhat right (in any sense)”.

*Leftish*, on the other hand, is burdened with a political sense. From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leftish#English), *leftish* means “(politics) Leaning towards the political left”.  For use of *leftish* as a  spatial-relation term, let me refer you to a description of it that comprises more than four pages of phrases like the following:

> Clearly, then, we require some understanding of what counts as a leftish experience. After all, something counts as being to the left only relative to an orientation, so something counts as a leftish experience only relative to some orientation.  Now,  leftish experiences are normally initially conceived of as the experience of a location to one's left when one is sitting upright, looking straight ahead, and when one's face is level.  Yet this way of discerning what counts as a  leftish experience does not tell us what makes the experience leftish.  Relative to what does the experience count as left?  One natural way is to assume that a leftish-experience  counts as left by reference to the center of your visual field.  ... *Reference and Referring, A Framework*, Jessica Pepp, in *[Reference and Referring](http://books.google.com/books?id=CjHZvQa9vx0C&pg=PA45&dq=%22leftish%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O4NnVJjrPKa3mwXD64BA&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22leftish%22&f=false)*, ed. W. P. Kabasenche, M. O'Rourke, M. H. Slater, MIT Press, 2012, pp. 45-48

Even if both of *rightish* and *leftish* worked properly for senses like  “to the right” and  “to the left”, the corresponding term  *uppish* has a problem.  It usually doesn't express a spatial sense, because the most-commonly-understood sense of *[uppish](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uppish#Adjective)* is “Proud; arrogant; assuming; putting on airs of superiority”.   (A less-commonly-known sense *is* spatially related:  “(cricket, of a shot) In which the ball is hit into the air, with the chance of being caught”.)

*Downish* is rare and many dictionaries don't list it.  OED1 (1897) lists it as an obsolete adjective, formed from *down* plus *-ish*:

> Downish, a. Obs. [f. Down a. + -ISH.]
>   Somewhat dejected or directed downward.

As a final note, [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uppish%2Cdownish%2Cleftish%2Crightish&year_start=1776&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuppish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdownish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleftish%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crightish%3B%2Cc0) for *uppish,downish,leftish,rightish* shows that  *uppish*  and *leftish* are used much more commonly than are  *downish* and *rightish*.   *Uppish* has had the most staying power over the years, but *leftish* has in the last 50 years made a concerted effort to overtake and temporarily surpass it in popularity.  *Downish*'s flash of fame occurred 1795-1802, although OED1's references for it are a hundred years older.